# Reverse hashcat mask

Tags: bash, parsing, scripting, passwords, hashcat

It is possible to use hashcat to generate a dictionary file based on a "mask" where the argument for hashcat looks like ?l?l?l?l?l?l?l?l for the pattern of an 8 char all lowercase passwords.

Other charsets looks like

```
?u = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
?d = 0123456789
?h = 0123456789abcdef
?H = 0123456789ABCDEF
?s = «space»!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
?a = ?l?u?d?s
?b = 0x00 - 0xff
```

I'm trying to do the opposite where I feed a dictionary file (like rockyou or something) into the script, and it will return the top 10 patterns.

Can this be done in bash?

Answer (score 0):

`statsgen` from [the PACK toolkit](https://github.com/Hydraze/pack) will save masks by frequency to a file if you use its `-o [outfile]` option.